# Pulling data from a list in SharePoint 2013 via REST

Tags: c#, rest, sharepoint, azure, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to build a mobile service in Azure (C#) that pushes data onto client apps. The data I need to pull is from a sharepoint site which I'm not very familiar with nor do I have access to.

I've read a couple of resources online but whenever I try to quickly visit the list via **_api/web/lists/** or **_api/web/lists/getbytitle('pages')**, I get an authentication prompt.

Is this the default behavior or hsa the rest api been switched off? Do I need to build a sharepoint app to generate an oauth token and then access the list?

I'm basically clueless so any piece of information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

use the following URLs:

- **Get all lists** `http://servername/_api/web1/web2/lists/`
- **Get list by title**  `http://servername/_api/web1/web2/lists/GetByTitle('myList')`
- **Get all items in specific** list `http://servername/_api/web1/web2/lists/GetByTitle('myList')/items`
- **list item by item ID** `http://servername/_api/web1/web2/lists/GetByTitle('myList')/items/GetItemById(4)`
- **Return items with specific fields** `http://servername/_api/web1/web2/lists/GetByTitle('myList')/items?$select=Title,Age`

For more detail, please visit the link http://wmostafaw.wordpress.com/2012/11/17/odata-in-sharepoint-2013-lists-and-items/

Answer (score 1):

That is default behavior.  You will need credentials to access the REST Services and you have create a Digest to do this programmatically:

```
String retVal = "";
    try
    {
         string url = "https://YourSite.com/";
         HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true });
          client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(url);
          string cmd = "_api/contextinfo";
          client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
          client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentType", "application/json");
          client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentLength", "0");
          StringContent httpContent = new StringContent("");
          var response = client.PostAsync(cmd, httpContent).Result;
          if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
          {
              string content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
               JsonObject val = JsonValue.Parse(content).GetObject();
               JsonObject d = val.GetNamedObject("d");
               JsonObject wi = d.GetNamedObject("GetContextWebInformation");
               retVal = wi.GetNamedString("FormDigestValue");
           }
     }
     catch
     { }
return retVal;
```

If you have an account that can access the list in SharePoint then you should be able to use that same account to authenticate against the REST Service and retrieve the list items once you pass it the Digest.  If you get one I have a lot of code examples on my blog for this type of application.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bunch of content from MSDN on this: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

There are a lot of code samples here too: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj860569%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: I've vaguely mentioned those in bold above. I guess I was asking if authentication is required by default or not, given that all I'm doing is a GET operation.
From all the code, I assume that an oauth token is always required and guess my next question leads to generating that token in an app hosted outside of sharepoint.

Comment: Yes, you need to be authenticated. The claims-model is somewhat more complicated that on-prem SharePoint auth.  See this sample for how to prompt for login details: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-Online-0bdeb2ca/view/Discussions